# Button group and MVC questions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, radio-button, bootstrap-4

I'm making a Radio Buttons Button Group using Bootstrap latest version (following [this tutorial](https://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/creating-radio-buttons-using-bootstrap-and-mvc)), on a field `bool?` (`true/false`) from my Model. Here's my code:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Paid, true) Paid
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Paid, false) Not Paid
    </label>
</div>
```

which renders in this way:

[image]

But I've some problems:

1. how can I hidden the "radio" check on rendering? I see it next the (fontawesome) icon;
2. how can I manage this with LabelFor from MVC? So it apply the class "active" when the input is `true`;
3. since its a `bool?`, how can I manage the case `null`? Right now its only for `true` or `false`;

Hope you can help me with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I hidden the "radio" check on rendering? I see it within the
>   icon

You should add the class `btn-group-toggle` for this

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" role="group" data-toggle="buttons">
```

> how can I manage this with LabelFor from MVC? So it apply the class "active" when the input is true;

You should do something like this.

```
<%
if(Model.isPaid == true) { 
%>
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Paid, true, new {@checked="checked"}) Paid
    </label>
<%
}
%>
```

> since its a bool?, how can I manage the case null? Right now its only for true or false;

Initially if neither of the radio buttons are checked, the value will be `null`. If you select any radio button the value will thereafter either `true` or `false` . You cannot make it `null` after a selection is made.